# Get Button Text

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Button composable that I need to get the text value when clicked.

```
Button(
     onClick = {// Get the "TheText" from below },
     ) {
     Text(
      modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
      text = "TheText",
      style = TextStyle(fontSize = 15.sp)
      )
}
```

I am creating a type of quiz where the buttons text matches the correct answer.

I thin I may need to create a custom compposabe that takes the text as a parameter and also a callback function that will pass that text back up to my main program where I can Check for a correct answer.

Comment: What is your use case?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to input text instead of just displaying one.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun example() {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("TheText") }

    Column {
       Button(
         onClick = {
           val useThisString = text
         },
       ) { Text(text = text) } // Probably wanna put "Copy" here 
       TextField(
          value = text,
          onValueChange = { text = it },
          label = { Text("Optinal Label") }
       )
   }
}
```

Otherwise, if you just want the label of the button:

```kotlin
val buttonText = "TheText"
Button(
     onClick = {
       // Use variable here
     },
) {
     Text(
      modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
      text = buttonText,
      style = TextStyle(fontSize = 15.sp)
      )
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I added a use case above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's how to store it in a variable

```
var retrievedValue by mutableStateOf("") //Assuming you must use it somewhere else as state

var currentValue by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("The Text") }

Button(
     onClick = { retrievedValue = currentValue },
     ) {
     Text(
      modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
      text = currentValue,
      style = TextStyle(fontSize = 15.sp)
      )
}
```

Now you can use it anywhere you want. Changing the `retrievedValue` would trigger recompositions in any composable that reads it.

This should solve your problem. Use the retrievedValue as the value returned by a callback. In compose, for such stuff, you do not need callbacks. `MutableState` objects, whenever are modified, trigger a recomposition on the composables reading them.

Anyway, here when you click the button, you will get the value of the text, whatever it may be, you will always get the current value.

Comment: Thanks I added a use case above.